# Contact form 7 email subject should be post title

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form, subject

I am using custom form 7

I want that, If anyone clicks the mail button under single post in wordpress, it will automatically redirect him to contact-us page and then subject of the mail will be the post title.

How can I do that?

Comment: I know that some simple php magic will do the job. on contact page codes, using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFER­ER'] to detect the referrer url. then the url_to_postid() function to get the id from that url. when you have id, you can do anything with it.

Comment: But I dont know exactly where I will add those

Comment: On the page where you send the email?

Comment: The email will be sent to server address.Thats not the matter.Everything is now ok but now I want that subject area of the email will be filled by post title from where visitor has been redirected to contact page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with this code:

```
<?php
if( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] !== '' ) {
    $referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $id = url_to_postid($referer);
    $subject = get_the_title($id);
} else {
    $subject = '';
}
?>
```

input field:`<input id="post-referer" value="<?php echo esc_attr($subject); ?>" type="hidden">`

then used jQuery to fill up the subject field from 'post-referer' field's value.

Answer (score 3):

Haven't used it before, but this plugin claims to work for your purposes: https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/

You will then create your mail link to contain the post title via a query parameter with (maybe with [http_build_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-str.php)), so that your URL becomes like:

```
http://example.com/contact-us/?title=my+post+title
```

After which you have to create the new CF7 tag as such, to auto-populate with the $_GET variable.

```
[dynamictext post_subject "CF7_GET key='title'"]
```

Comment: where will I create http_build_str() ?

Comment: At the place where you want to make the mail link. It's just a function to help append a query string to a specific URL.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install [Contact Form 7 Dynamic Text Extension](https://srd.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/) and use  fields in your form this way.

CF7:

```
[dynamictext post_subject "CF7_GET key='title'"]
```

The `key` is the name of parameter of your url.

Comment: kindly add some explanation to your answer

Comment: This is the same answer as below. Please don't post duplicate answers.